# Replace comma delimiter in a multi-select choice column

Tags: list, list-view, column, view, choice-field

A SharePoint list has a multi-select choice field.

When 2 or more values are selected for an item,it is displayed(in the view)as:

Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Value6

Is there a way that I can display this field as shown below?

Value1,
Value2,
Value3,
Value4,
Value5,
Value6

Comment: Are you 2013? Then look into CSR - ClientSideRendering

Comment: @DannyEngelman No,I'm in 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

1. Download [jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js) and save it to `/SiteAssets/`
2. Create a JavaScript file named `comma-break.js` and save it in `/SiteAssets/` with the contents of:

`$(document).ready(function () {
    var str = $('.ms-listviewtable').html();
    //;
    $('.ms-listviewtable').html(str.replace(new RegExp(", ", "g"), ",</br>"));
});`

3. Add a Content Editor Web Part to your list and link to the `jquery.min.js` file.
4. Add a Content Editor Web Part to your list and link to the `comma-break.js` file.

Comment: also I assumed in that code, that you meant semi-colon instead of colon. If you in fact meant colon than just replace the two semi-colons in the code with colons.

Comment: when i tried your script,the field value became invisible.

Comment: Sorry about that! I should have verified the code before submitting. I updated the code and it appears to work for me. Please let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: You may want to change `</a>;` to `, ` and `</a>;</br>` to `,</br>` The list I was originally playing with was a multi-lookup select instead of just a multi-select.

Comment: I have the below script now and its not working.    $(document).ready(function(){
var str=$('.ms-listviewtable').html();
//;
$('.ms-listviewtable').html(str.replace( new RegExp(",","g"),",</br>"));
});

Comment: Give me a moment to review.

Comment: So the script I commented is right? do i need to include any other js files?

Comment: Yes, ok the problem is you also need jQuery for the code I provided. I have updated my answer which should solve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26713/discussion-between-james-flattery-and-george).