# How to change the output of a Multi-value Lookup column in a View?

Tags: 2013, list-view, lookup-column, list-view-web-part

Could I edit the way the Lookup column displays information, if possible without code? (Or an easy explanation as to how to do it?).

Currently it is displaying as "Name; Name; Name; Name". I would like there to be at least line breaks between each item.

If possible, my second goal would be to make the two columns I got from the Lookup (main Lookup + joint column) to display in a table. Any of this easily done?

Comment: None of it without code. What version of SharePoint are you on?

Comment: This may answer your question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/151671/38758

Comment: It does answer my question but doens't seem to work. I'm on SP 2013.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**

in June 2017, Microsoft disabled the use of JavaScript in a Calculated Column

That means given answers may not apply  for newer SharePoint versions

For long explanation and work arounds see:
[June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

---

**Original answer:**

This works **in VIEWS** on SP2010,13,16 & Online, and does not require jQuery or any extra JavaScript files or (Content Editor) WebParts

**Disclaimer:** you need minor JavaScript skills (just to understand what you are copy pasting), and debugging this code is PITA

The Lookup info you are after is actually available in the Context object **once the VIEW has loaded**, so you can access it with either CSR (Client side Rendering) or....

Stuff some Javascript in a Calculated Column... less lines compared to CSR.. but difficult to debug if you don't get the syntax right.

**instructions**

On the View page, Open F12 console and check the exact spelling for your Lookup Column (internal fieldname) in: `ctx.ListData.Row[0]` (*paste this Array reference and hit enter, it will display the value for the first displayed List-Item*)

Then create a Calculated Column, set the datatype to Number so it executes the HTML!
(*You only want this on the List, if you have ContentTypes, do NOT add this Column to ContentTypes*)

Formula:

```
="<div style=""text-align:left""><img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
  &"var TR=this;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"
  &"var item=ctx.ListData.Row[TR.rowIndex-1];"
  &"this.parentNode.innerHTML=item['Title'].replace(/;/g,'<br>');"
&"}""></div>"
```

**replace Title with the internal fieldname of your Column** (*The internal name is the name of the Column when you first created it*)

**explanation**

- The onload function is triggered once the blank image is loaded.
- The Table Row has the rowIndex.. but the first table row in the View Table is the Header row so we have to subtract -1
- at the end the whole IMG tag is overwritten with the Lookup string replacing ; with BR tags

Detailed explanation and Pros & Cons at [www.ViewMaster365.com/#How](http://www.ViewMaster365.com/#How)

iCC

Comment: However this may work, I'm keeping it as a last resort since I'm reluctant to start in what I consider difficult code...

Comment: I am trying to make this work. I have pasted code into calculated column, I'm in F12 console. Where do I find the exact internal fieldname? I can only find the code I entered, nothing's changed.

Could you maybe show me by having the name of my lookupcolumn as 'Test' and the name of my calculated column as 'Test2'?

Comment: Paste ``ctx.ListData.Row[0]`` in the F12 Console and hit enter, that will show the values of first Item in the list. if Test is your columnname replace YOURINTERNALNAME with Test

Comment: Rewritten Formula should be easier to use

Comment: This works for the views, but any idea on how to make it work in DispForm.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the content query webpart, this should do just what you're looking for. It grabs information from a list and the output can be styled to your fitting

Comment: You mean, instead of using Lookup column?

Comment: Users need to select info from the list, that's why I used lookup. Is there a way to let users make a selection that I can then use to retrieve files?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([Modified answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/151671/38758)):

1. Download [jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js) and save it to `/SiteAssets/`
2. Create a JavaScript file named `comma-break.js` and save it in `/SiteAssets/` with the contents of:

`$(document).ready(function () {
    var str = $('.ms-listviewtable').html();
    //;
    $('.ms-listviewtable').html(str.replace( new RegExp("</a>;","g"),"</a>;</br>"));
});`

3. Add a Content Editor Web Part to your list and link to the `jquery.min.js` file.
4. Add a Content Editor Web Part to your list and link to the `comma-break.js` file.